# Вывод Гистограми

Tags: python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30, 5))


ax.bar(x,y)
ax.grid()

plt.show()
```

Comment: Вопросы из разряда "не имею мысли" обычно закрывают. Не может быть, чтобы в задаче, где подробно расписаны отдельные шаги, вам не было понятно вообще ничего. Хоть что-то вы могли бы реализовать, а там глядишь и с остальным разобрались либо вам бы помогли.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Зачем же вы само задание удалили? В вопросе должны быть: 1) описание задания; 2) ваши попытки решить его, включая ваши мысли по поводу задачи и ваш код; 3) описание ваших проблем - что не так с вашим кодом, что не удалось сделать.

Answer (score 1):

1. кол-во экспериментов реализуете через цикл `for`
2. кол-во испытаний реализуете через второй цикл `for`
3. случайное событие (орел/решка) реализуете через библиотеку `random` и функцию `randint(0, 1)`
4. в зависимости от наступившего события увеличиваете счетчик орлов/решек
5. по результатам заносите данные в список экспериментов
6. отображаете список

P.S.

если кол-во испытаний не слишком большое, то  2) - 3) можно выполнить за одну команду

```
print(random.choices([0, 1], weights=[1, 1], k=100))
```